# Find $\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor^2}{x^2 - 4}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

How to find $\lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor^2}{x^2 -  4}$

My textbook says limit doesn't exist but graph says it's zero.

Comment: I assume they meant that $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor^2}{x^2 -  4}$ which doesn't exist,anyway you're right your limit is equal to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph is correct.  If $x$ is just above 2, the numerator is 4-4=0, and the denominator isn't.